# Moving blog from Wordpress.com to self-hosted : How to install CORE widgets/plugins

Tags: wordpress, self-hosting

I was able to export the blog from a wordpress.com site to a self-hosted one.

However, I am having issues installing the 'CORE widgets' (http://en.support.wordpress.com/topic/widgets-sidebars/). Are these locked down to wordpress.com only?

Thanks!

Comment: which one specific are you looking for? Most of them are open.

Comment: I am looking at Twitter, Box.net, Authors, Flickr, SocialVibe Gravatar among few. 

I want to restore as much functionality as possible and want to use the same plugins - (using similar plugins would be my next preference - ).. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure these widgets weren't installed as part of your theme?

Comment: ya.. I am using the twenty10 theme.. these widgets were not there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so you go this way: automattic is a company behind wordpress and they often open-source their extra stuff, look at their profile: http://profiles.wordpress.org/automattic/

So:

twitter - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wickett-twitter-widget/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/authors/

For others search: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/